# Definition Chemical Potential

Tags: statistical-mechanics, chemical-potential

Chemical potential is a change in internal energy when a particle is added  to system.

now what if a system contain lots of energy state in this case if you add a particle to two distinct energy state the change in energy will be different, so what will be the correct chemical potential?

Comment: if you *move* a particle between  two distinct energy states  internal energy will be different, so what will be the correct internal energy?